# How BCC works in Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, python, ruby

I'm trying to use postfix feature content_filter like:

```
my_script unix  -      n        n       -      10        pipe
  flags=Rq user=filter argv=/usr/local/bin/my_script.py -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

And my question is, how I can check BCC recipient in my script? My script is only reinjecting e-mail back to the postfix. I don't want to change anything with it, and I don't want to save it as a file. I simply need to read each e-mail from postfix from stdin. But when I'm doing it my BCC are ignored, I'm able to send e-mails only to: [TO and CC]. I think that's because BCC is not in the header, so my question is, where is it and how to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**All** recipient in TO, CC, BCC will be passed on `{recipient}` parameter in your script. For example if you have

- a@example.net and b@example.net in TO address
- p@example.com in CC address
- z@example.org in BCC address
- me@example.info as sender

then postfix will call your script with

```
/usr/local/bin/my_script.py -f me@example.info -- a@example.net b@example.net p@example.com z@example.org
```